# How to handle net errors in golang properly

Tags: go

I do not get how one can handle errors receiving from the net package. I need to know what kind of error occurred to do the next step. Trying to parse the error message string is probably not the right way...

```
response, err := data.httpClient.Get("https://" + domain)
if err != nil {             
    fmt.Println("[!] error: ", err)
    /* 
    *  I want something like this in pseudo code:
    *  if error == DnsLookupError {
    *      action1()
    *  } else if error == TlsCertificateError {
    *      action2()
    *  } else if error == Timeout {
    *      action3()
    *  } ...
    */
}
```

Error messages I receive for example:

```
Get "https://example1.com": remote error: tls: internal error
Get "https://example2.com": dial tcp: lookup example2.com
etc.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check whether the error is compatible with a few well-known error types. I [did it like this](https://github.com/rillig/pkglint/blob/0281937830488986b73f4aad8c72e111d6c5b75f/homepage.go#L339):

```golang
func classifyNetworkError(err error) string {
    cause := err
    for {
        // Unwrap was added in Go 1.13.
        // See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36781
        if unwrap, ok := cause.(interface{ Unwrap() error }); ok {
            cause = unwrap.Unwrap()
            continue
        }
        break
    }

    // DNSError.IsNotFound was added in Go 1.13.
    // See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28635
    if cause, ok := cause.(*net.DNSError); ok && cause.Err == "no such host" {
        return "name not found"
    }

    if cause, ok := cause.(syscall.Errno); ok {
        if cause == 10061 || cause == syscall.ECONNREFUSED {
            return "connection refused"
        }
    }

    if cause, ok := cause.(net.Error); ok && cause.Timeout() {
        return "timeout"
    }

    return sprintf("unknown network error: %s", err)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `errors.As(..)` do the unwrapping for you? https://go.dev/play/p/GRljxCx42bh

Comment: When I wrote the code from my answer, I still had to support Go 1.12, that's why I couldn't use anything from Go 1.13, and `errors.As` was introduced in Go 1.13.

Comment: Ah, ok, the `// Unwrap was added in Go 1.13.` comment confused me. Will update to assume 1.13 since it was released 3+ years ago.